# Zooming of image view in not working correctly in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is the point where I got stuck for the past one week.
I'm displaying an image in a `UIImageView`. Users have an option for zooming the images.
The images is being fetched from a server.

When the user zooms the image, we are sending x1,x2,y1,y2 (of imageview) points to the server and the corresponding zoomed image is fetched from the server and being displayed.

The zoom is working only for the first time. When the user tried to zoom again and again, it is not working.

For this, I have set a bool value named windowPanZoomOccured.

```
- (void)pinchGestureHandler:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
            windowPanZoomOccured = TRUE;


                [self handleGestureEventWebserviceForGesture:@"zoom-out" withGestureObject:gesture_ andframeId:currentFrame_];

}//gesture_ object contains the points and velocity.

//Code for checking whether zoom event fired or not.
if (windowPanZoomOccured) 
        {
            NSLog(@"The value of the bool here in unpackdata %@\n", (windowPanZoomOccured ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
            NSLog(@"enter here");
            imageView.image = Nil;

            imageView.image = image;
           // [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];


            windowPanZoomOccured = FALSE;
        }
```

I tried by  // [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay]; But its not working. Any ideas ???

Answer (score 0):

You can put the imageview into a scrollView and do the zoom callback in

> - (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

Comment: its not possible.new images are generate at the server according to the point we pass from here'